# SDL_Texture opacity

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

How can I change opacity of the SDL_Texture? And I don't know how to apply the opacity number in my function.

My code

```
    void drawTexture(SDL_Texture *img, int x, int y, int width, int height, double opacity)
    {
        SDL_Rect SrcR;
        SDL_Rect DestR;

        SrcR.x = 0;
        SrcR.y = 0;
        SrcR.w = width;
        SrcR.h = height;

        DestR.x = x;
        DestR.y = y;
        DestR.w = width;
        DestR.h = height;

        SDL_RenderCopy(_main::_main_renderer, img, &SrcR, &DestR);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod):

```
SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(img, opacity);
```

This will set the opacity (alpha) of the texture, the alpha value must be a `Uint8` from `0` (totally transparent aka invisible) to `255` (fully opaque).

Comment: Thanks but there must be opacity 0-255.

Comment: in that case you can pass it to the function like this:
`SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(img, opacity / 255.0);`

Comment: @xorguy: you're wrong. opacity must be a unsigned int, so from 0 to 255. This formula will be used: srcA = srcA * (opacity / 255)

Answer (score 0):

Opening question doesn't have info on the origin of **img** texture so the chosen answer it not correct it the texture is created from raw pixel data that doesn't have Alpha, i.e. using this:

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(img, NULL, pixels, pitch);
```

If **pixels** contains raw pixel data without alpha, i.e. ARGB with **A** 0x00, even if you do this

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(img, NULL, pixels, pitch);
SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(img, opacity);
```

you will not see the texture (in this case alpha is 0x00) or you'll see garbage